# Tensorflow Runs on GPU on home PC but not on Google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train the neural network in this repo on google colab:
https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow

I'm running this code on Google Colab (with hardware accelerator set to GPU), and the training is 40 times slower than running on my home PC which has a much weaker GTX 1050. So I'm guessing on colab it is not running on the GPU.  The output on google colab does indicate the GPU was found though:

Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Based on [this page](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb) it seems like it should work - does the code there help?

Comment: Can you share a minimal repro notebook that demonstrates the problem, and relative timings from your GPU and colab's?

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason behind this data that that need time to come from driver to colab
what about try GPU on parallel function 100 times in both that does not need data
to run and tell me results

after all i found [example](https://github.com/llSourcell/how_to_make_an_image_classifier/blob/master/demo.ipynb) 
that could finish first Epoch in 39 seconds when i try it it seems that colab take time to transfer data for each photo that i have and took in first Epoch 332s after initial things
every-time you will run both he will get 39 seconds  and i will get 332 s

i hope this help